# HTML reusing components

Tags: html

I have an HTML component I want to reuse on several pages. For the sake of elegance, I would like to reuse the component rather than copy and paste it.

This is a tricky question, in my searches I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096681/developing-reusable-html-components) post, which simply says it is not possible in pure html. But then I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-website-into-a-div-of-a-html-page) post, which seems like it could accomplish exactly what I want.
So, which one is right?

For reference, here is the component that I'm trying to reuse:

```
<div id="topbar" class="container">
    <div class="test1">
        <p> Style1
    </div>

    <div class="test2">
        <p> Style2
    </div>

    <div id="test3">
        <p> Style3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The one the says you can provides code, so this is easy to test for yourself.

Comment: Most developers use a serverside language with serverside includes. And that second on is not PURE html, it is JavaScript.

Comment: Put it in a seperate HTML file and use the Jquery load() method. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Quentin This isn't just a question about those 2 examples, it is a broader question about component reuse in* html. From my mention of elegance I was hoping for hints at good coding practice, but really I'm happy with anything.

Comment: @epascarello — The second one uses an object element, which is pure HTML

Comment: Popped a +1 only because there was a googled attempt, but it seems that this is person is starting from ground 0, and needs answers directed that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure html does not have the reusable component architecture, however there are several options.

- jQuery: You can execute a load, to grab your HTML fragment from a file and embed it into your page.
- Angular.Js: You can create a custom directive that acts like an HTML tag, but renders as your HTML fragment
- Server Side Includes: If this feature is included in your server, then you can implement this.

  - ASP: `<!--#include file="my fragment file name"-->`
- Server code execution: Like server side includes, if you are running on a server that supports PHP, ASP, Ruby, ASP.NET, or one of several other languages, you can have them embed the code snipped into your HTML at the server.

  - ASP.NET C#: `@MyStringVariable`
  - PHP: `include("my fragment file name");`

Your question is one of the first of stepping into the huge world of software engineering and web development.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with server side languages, so if you're using PHP you can do this

```
include("MyMarkup.php");
```

or if you're using ASP , you can do this

```
<!--#include file="includefile.asp"-->
```

Comment: +1 for workable solution (also I didn't like that someone downvoted this w/o a comment D:<)